# Lemma to prove Poincaré-Bendixson theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to understand the following proof of the lemma used as a part of Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem, but I don't get it the blue equality in the proof. Can someone explain it?

**Lemma.** If $p \in \Sigma \cap \omega(\gamma)$, where $\Sigma$ is a transversal line of $X$ and $\gamma = \{\varphi(t)\}$ an orbit of $X$, then $p$ can be expressed as a limit of a sequence of points $\varphi(t_n) \in \Sigma$, where $t \to +\infty$.

**Proof.** Let $\gamma = \{\varphi(t)\} = \{\varphi(t,q)\}$  and $p \in \Sigma \cap \omega(\gamma)$. Consider a neighborhood $V$ and the function $\tau:V \to \mathbb{R}$ given by the theorem below. By definition we know that exists a sequence $(\bar{t}_n)$ such that $\bar{t}_n \to \infty$ and $\varphi(\bar{t}_n) \to p$ when $n \to \infty$.

[Illustration of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ayjc.png)

Then exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\varphi(\bar{t}_n) \in V, \forall n\geq n_0$. Let $t_n = \bar{t}_n + \tau(\varphi(\bar{t}_n))$ for $n \geq n_0$, then
\begin{equation}
\varphi(t_n) = \color{blue}{\varphi(\bar{t}_n + \tau(\varphi(\bar{t}_n)),q) = \varphi(\tau(\varphi(\bar{t}_n)),\varphi(\bar{t}_n))}.
\end{equation}
By defition of $\tau$ we obtain that $\varphi(t_n) \in \Sigma$. As $\tau$ is continuous and $\tau(\varphi(\bar{t}_n)) \to \tau(p) = 0$,
\begin{equation}
\lim \varphi(t_n) = \lim \varphi(\tau(\varphi(\bar{t}_n)),\varphi(\bar{t}_n)) = \varphi(0,p) = p.
\end{equation}

**Theorem.** Let $\Sigma$ be a transversal section of $X$. For any $p \in \Sigma$ exists a $\epsilon = \epsilon(p)$, a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a function $\tau: V \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\tau(V\cap \Sigma) = 0$ and

1. for all $q \in V$, the solution $\varphi(t,q)$ of $X|_V$ is defined and 1-1 in $J_q = (-\epsilon+\tau(q), \epsilon + \tau(q))$;
2. $\xi(q) = \varphi(\tau(q),q) \in \Sigma$ is the only point where $\varphi(\cdot,q)|_{J_q}$ intercept $\Sigma$. In particular, $q \in \Sigma \cap V \iff \tau(q)=0$;
3. $\xi: V \to \Sigma$ is $C^k$ and $D\xi(q)$ is surjective for any $q \in V$.

**Notes.**

1. $X: \Delta \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is the vector field associate with the ode $x'=X(x)$;
2. $\varphi(t, q)$ is the solution the ode above that passes through the point $q$.

Comment: This is just the group property of the flow, $\phi(s+t;q)=\phi(s;\phi(t;q))$. Or in terms of the DE, for an autonomous DE, from every solution $\phi(t)$ you get other, shifted solutions $\phi(t+a)$. These all have different initial points at $t=0$, that however are points on the curve.

Comment: Oh, you are right. More simple than I expected. Thank you!